# How to tell which amqp message was not routed from basic.return response?

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I'm using RabbitMQ with node-amqp lib. I'm publishing messages with mandatory flag set, and when there is no route to any queue, RabbitMQ responds with `basic.return` as in specification.

My problem is that, as far as I can tell, `basic.return` is asynchronous and does not contain any information about for which message no queue was found. Even when exchange is in confirm mode). How the hell am I supposed to tell which message was returned?

Comment: It would be in help if you provide more info, like language and libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

node-amqp emits `'basic-return'` event on receiving the `basic.return` from amqp. Only thing of any use there is routing key. Since all messages with the same routing key are routed the same way. I assumed that once I get a `basic.return` about a specific routing key, all messages with this routing key can be considered undelivered

```js
function deliver(routing_key, message, exchange, resolve, reject){
    var failed_delivery = function(ret){
        if(ret.routingKey == routing_key){
            exchange.removeListener('basic-return', failed_delivery);
            reject(new Error('failed to deliver'));
        }
    };
    exchange.on('basic-return', failed_delivery);
    exchange.publish( 
        routing_key,
        message,
        {   deliveryMode: 1, //non-persistent
            mandatory: true
        }, function(error_occurred, error){
            exchange.removeListener('basic-return', failed_delivery);
            if(error_occurred){
                reject(error);
            } else {
                resolve();
            }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I read the AMQP spec, because I've used the Basic Return without a problem before, but I'm also using the .NET client.  I looked through the documentation on node-amqp, and I can't even see that it implements Basic.Return.

In any event, the server does respond with the full message when it could not be published.  You may consider switching to a different Node.js library (for example, [`amqplib`](http://squaremo.github.io/amqp.node/doc/channel_api.html) does have this feature (marked as `Channel#on('return', function(msg) {...})`).